# Connect ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Interbase XE7 using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient (7.5.0) and Dapper

Tags: firebird, dapper, asp.net-core-3.1, interbase

I am trying to connect ASP.NET Core 3.1 with an Interbase XE7 database. For the connection with the Interbase database, I'm using the  `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` (v7.5.0) Nuget package with Dapper.

The database connection string is:

```
"DefaultConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Database=127.0.0.1:\\<db_name>;Uid=SYSDBA;Pwd=masterkey"
```

Dapper connection code :

```
using (var connection = new FbConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")))
{
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
}
```

Running this code results in an exception:

[image: exception]

Looking at the internet for possible solution suggests changing firebird.conf file for

```
WireCrypt  
AuthServer 
AuthClient
```

properties but I did not install Firebird on my system.

Am I in right direction or missing something?

Comment: Isn't there some native C# library for Interbase? There surely is one for Java (InterClient or something), not sure about C#. Any expectations that Firebird library would work with not-Firebird server is quite optimistic... You might also try chances with a commercial OLE library from https://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation.html

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Machado recently Embarcadero has expands InterBase support for Visual Studio. So you may want to look at this article https://blogs.embarcadero.com/embarcadero-expands-interbase-support-for-visual-studio/

Comment: @Machado I have tried the newly released C# library for InterBase and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

The *connection rejected by remote interface* means that the client and server could not agree on a protocol version while attempting to connect. Even though Firebird and Interbase have a shared history, they have diverged a lot over the past 20 years. The FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient ADO.net provider does not support Interbase<sup>1</sup>. It only supports Firebird. So you cannot use it to connect to Interbase XE7.

You will need to use a driver that supports Interbase, or switch to Firebird.

---

<sup>1: The comments in [DNET-245](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-245) and [DNET-314](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-314) indicate that Interbase is not supported</sup>